# angular 5 routing is reloading the entire page

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm having a problem with angular 5.
I used a fresh install with angular cli : ng new Test --routing, but it seems to reload the entire page not only the  part.
Did someone had the same problem?

Routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {GalleryComponent} from './gallery/gallery.component';
import {MainComponent} from './main/main.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'gallery',
        component: GalleryComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Navigation code

```
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="/gallery">Galerie</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If root component template contains only router-outlet tag - then yes, routing component will fill all the space so whole page will change on routing event

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk I added the entire code from app.component.html
It is not containing only the <router-outlet> tag

Comment: It reloads the whole page when doing what? What is the relevant code? You haven't posted any link allowing to navigate, any routing configuration

Comment: I edited the post. It reloads the whole page when I'm trying to navigate.

Comment: That's not how you navigate. You must use routerLink. Read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links. You've lost at least 41 minutes on this problem. That's more than it takes to read the routing documentation, and learn a whole lot of things while doing it.

Comment: Ohh god... My bad, I read it but i don't know how I missed it. My bad sorry

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should try using `routerLink` instead of `href` attribute in your `<a>` tags.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/gallery">Galerie</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

A standard `href` will tell the browser to navigate to the given URL. But what you want is telling Angular to navigate to the URL.

Comment: this makes the world of sense when I actually think about it (palm to forehead)  Good Work Thank You